# Given a sequence, construct a function whose integral is equal to the sum of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $P_n$ be the sequence of prime numbers, where $P_0=2$.

Given $m\in\mathbb{N}$, how can we construct $f(x)$ such that:

- $\displaystyle\forall{0}\leq{i}\leq{m}:f(i)=P_i$
- $\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{m}f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m}P_i$

For example, given $m=2$, how can we construct $f(x)$ such that:

- $f(0)=2,f(1)=3,f(3)=5$
- $\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{2}f(x)=2+3+5=10$

Answers for specific values of $m$ will also be appreciated.

Comment: Do you expect $0 = \int_0^0 f(x)\,dx = \sum_{i = 0}^{0}P_i = P_0 = 2$ to hold?

Comment: @JimmyK4542: $m\in\mathbb{N}$!!!

Comment: $f(x) = \tilde{P}(x) + \frac{P_0+P_m}{m}\sin^2(\pi x)$ where $\tilde{P}$ is a linear interpolation of $P_k$ over $[0,m]$.

Comment: I've seen $\mathbb{N}$ used to denote $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ as well as $\{1,2,\ldots\}$. "Regrettably, there seems to be no general agreement about whether to include 0 in the set of natural numbers." from [Natural Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html) on MathWorld.

Comment: @JimmyK4542: OK, sorry about the extra exclamation marks then :) ... In any case, I was referring to $m\geq1$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to do if you take a [piecewise defined function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_defined_function). For example you could define:

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
2, &\text{if } x\in (-\infty,0]\\
7-4x, &\text{if } x\in (0,1]\\
P(i), &\text{if } x\in (i-1,i] \text{ for } i\geq2.
\end{cases}
$$

The only "problem" here seems to be the start, since it requires $\int_0^1f(x)dx=2+3=5$ and $f(1)=3$, so we cannot simply work with a constant function. But $7-4x$ has an average value of 5 for $0\leq x\leq 1$, so the integral condition is fulfilled.

For $x>1$ the integral behaves like a sum for natural values of $x$: since the function is constant in every interval of length 1 you simply add a rectangle with height $f(x)=P(i)$ to the integral.

It get's more complicated, if you want a continuous or even continuous differentiable function. Then you could use splines or trigonomic functions which have the property that for $x\in (i-1,i]$ the *average* function value is equal to $P(i)$.